# How to fix duplicated questions (using Readline() and return)

Tags: c#, return

I'm new to C#.
I'm creating a small program that input number by a user returns to the number and display it.
It works but a user is asked the same questions twice.
I just need one.
I'd appreciate if anyone help me with that.

Here is output of the program.
[image]

Here is my programming.
Class1

```
using System;
using System.Numerics;
using System.Reflection.Emit;
using static System.Console;
using System.IO;

namespace aaaa
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            TryReturn tryreturn = new TryReturn();
            tryreturn.template();
        }
     
    }
}
```

Class2

```
using System;
using System.Numerics;
using System.Reflection.Emit;
using static System.Console;
using System.IO;

namespace aaaa
{
    public class TryReturn
    {
        public int entryNum;

        public void template()
        {
            returnyNumber();
            DisplayNumber();
        }
        public void DisplayNumber()
        {
            entryNum = returnyNumber();
            WriteLine("number is " + entryNum);

            Read();
        }
        public int returnyNumber()
        {
            int entryNum;
            Write("Choose 1 or 2 >> ");
            do
            {
                int.TryParse(ReadLine(), out entryNum);
                if (entryNum == 1 || entryNum == 2)
                {
                    break;
                }
                else
                {
                    Write("Invalid entry! Enter either '1' or '2' >> ");
                }
            }
            while (true);
            return entryNum;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you calling `returnyNumber` from `template()` and ignoring the return value? (Side-note: I'd strongly advise you to start following .NET naming conventions as soon as possible.)

Comment: Follow the bread crumbs. Follow how your program executes, which methods in your code it calls, and which of your methods then call other methods in your code. Just follow what your code does step-by-step. Don't get distracted. If you have difficulties doing that "by eye", i guess it's a good time learning and practicing debugging skills, and use [Visual Studio's step debugger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/navigating-through-code-with-the-debugger) to observe what your program is doing line-by-line.

Answer (score 0):

```
//remove the call of returnyNumber from template as you are calling it from DisplayNumber
  public void template()
    {
        // returnyNumber();
        DisplayNumber();
    }
    public void DisplayNumber()
    {
        entryNum = returnyNumber();
        WriteLine("number is " + entryNum);

        Read();
    }
```